# Slow network connection maybe caused by wiring

Tags: gigabit-ethernet, powerline-networking

So today I got my new router and thus my new internet(1000mbit/s down - 50mbit/s up). The networking from my router to my computer is as follows:

Router -> Cat5e -> TL-PA8030P -> electrical wiring -> TL-PA8030P -> Cat7 -> Intel® I219V

Everything in this chain should support Gigabit the only problem is I still only get about 80-90mbit. This isn't caused by my isp because another pc is directly plugged into my router and gets 300mbit, it's a pretty old pc tho, and via wifi, I get around 400mbit.

I already tried every reachable outlet updated the powerline adapters firmware and also checked the tpPLC utility which is used to configure the powerline adapters.

So I thought after checking everything I have access to maybe my electrical wiring is just too old. And here we get to the confusing part my powerline adapters say (in the tpPLC utility) that they can communicate with each other with 250mbit. Currently I just can't understand what is throttling me to even get anywhere near gigabit speed.

Comment: Does the connection actually go through the power line or not? Your diagram shows only one TL-PA8030P device that both the router and the PC are connected to... Which is correct, the diagram or the text that follows?

Comment: @user1686 I'm sorry of course it goes through the powerline I'll update the diagram

Comment: Powerline adapters should only be a last resort. Many of them can only achieve a fraction of their advertised speeds under normal circumstances.